# Windows 7 safe mode screen default choice

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-restore

I have a Windows 7 computer that, when shut down improperly, boots up to the screen that gives a choice between starting windows normally and doing a system restore (and it has the 30 second timer). On this computer, the default choice is the system restore option. How do I change this so that the default choice is to start windows normally?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested, this may not be possible.

Try this simple workaround instead:

At the Command prompt enter the following:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

This will disable Startup Repair from automatically booting when there is a problem.

Comment: Thanks. I have run this command. The actual computer is at another location; I will check on it later this afternoon.