# Always skip the Safe Mode menu after Windows 7 crashes

Tags: windows-7

How do I make sure it skips the Safe Mode menu in Windows 7, after a crash or a shut down gone bad?

It's for a public computer and I have my reasons why this menu should never appear unless someone presses `F8` at startup.

`<rant>` I keep running into forums full of people who want to tell the OP that he should not disable Safe Mode and its dangerous and what not. Instead just answer the guy for crying out loud or stay away. `</rant>`

Finally I found someone who just answered the OP and since I couldn't up the answer or in some other way salute him I decided to do so here as I can’t be the only one with this requirement and want this answer to be more visible and easier to find.

BTW The original answer is [here](http://www.edugeek.net/forums/windows-7/71244-disable-safe-mode.html#post677163).

Comment: This should Disable the menu entirely: **bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no**                                                      
        
This one I tested and it works and will not show the safemode/boot menu after a crash:                           

    **bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures**

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/questions/609147/windows-7-safe-mode-screen-default-choice

Comment: Be sure you post an actual answer instead of using comments when you are able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should Disable the menu entirely.

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no
```

This one I tested and it works and will not show the safemode/boot menu after a crash:

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```